Expo problem with keystore (React Native)
I have problem when I build a project for production using expo.
When I have added a different keystore I got the problem, but when I removed the keystore and used the default the problem solved. I need to use a specific keystore so I can upload it to specific app on Google Play Store.
Build failed
 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" (https://expo.dev/accounts/x/projects/x/builds/ba47127e-fe56-4aed-a4b3-fdda32483f06#run-gradlew) phase for more information


